# Хочу открыть документ своим приложением. Как получить из него информацию?

Tags: python

Хочу сделать ассоциацию со своим приложением на python файлов вида *.txt. как мне возможно с помощью python получить путь до открываемого файла, его имя и (желательно) содержимое.

Проассоциировать можно стандартными средствами  windows, что-то вроде Open with MyApp.exe, а как выудить остальное?

Честно говоря, не знаю ни одного способа сделать это в python.

Comment: Уточнение: я просто хочу 2 раза кликнуть на файл и получить всю инфу в приложении

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] вашего приложения.

Comment: @S.Nick боюсь, что это не имеет смысла, т.к минимальным таким примером будет просто вывод в консоль пути до открываемого файла, но вывести я не могу, потому что для начала его надо передать как-то в "приложение"

Comment: Нет смысла в боязни!

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось очень тривиальным.

Билдим exe файл с помощью auto-py-to-exe, затем назначаем его как приложения для открытия файлов по умолчанию. Сам код внутри main.py

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
input()
```